# Group data frame given that they have something in common

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe of over 1000 lines that looks somewhat like this:

```
Copy    name        type    ntv
G1       BA          X      0.45
G1       BB          X      0.878
G1       C           Z      0.19
G1       LA1         Y      1.234
G1       L           Y      0.09
G1       LB          Y      1.056
F2       BA1         X      -7.890
F2       BB          X      2.345
F2       MA          Y      -0.871
F2       LB1         Y      0.737
```

In the example above (df1), there are two sets of the 'Copy' column, G1 and F2, with various names, and three types X,Y and Z.

I would like to create another data frame (df2) that looks like the one below, where they are grouped together in the form X-Y or Z-Y.

```
Model      ntv_1       ntv_2    
G1BA-LA1   0.45        1.234        
G1BB-LB    0.878       1.056    
G1C-L      0.19        0.09    
F2BA1-MA   -7.890      -0.871       
F2BB-LB1   2.345       0.737
```

For group X-Y, they have the second character of df1['name'] in common. So, I decided to approach it this way:

```
c = df1[(df1['name'].str[0]=='B' & (df1['ntv'] != 0.0)]
h = df1[((df1['name'].str[0]=='L')|(df1['name'].str[0]=='M')) & (df['ntv'] != 0.0)]
b = (c.loc[:,c['name'].str[1]] == h.loc[:,h['name'].str[1]]).groupby('Copy')
df2['Model'] = c['Copy'].astype(str) + c['name'].astype(str) + '-' + h['name'].astype(str)
df2['ntv_1'] = c['ntv']
df2['ntv_2'] = h['ntv']
```

I got a KeyError message. So I decided to do this:

```
ca = c['name'].str[1].dropna()
ha = h['name'].str[1].dropna()
if ca == ha:
  df2['Model'] = c['Copy'].astype(str) + c['name'].astype(str) + '-' + h['name'].astype(str)
  df2['ntv_1'] = c['ntv']
  df2['ntv_2'] = h['ntv']
```

But I got a ValueError: "Series length must match to compare."

Please how can I group the dataframe into the form X-Y or Z-Y? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why does BB go with LB and not L?

Comment: @ScottBoston It's because the single characters in df['name'] are paired together so long as they are in the same 'Copy'. That's why 'C' is paired with 'L'. Also, the X-type usually starts with letter 'B' while the Y-type usually starts with 'L' or 'M'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem `c` and `h` are not aligned, because different indices and possible different lenght:

```
#added condition for remove all rows with no second value in name
c = df1[(df1['name'].str[0]=='B') & (df1['ntv'] != 0.0) &
        (df1['name'].str[1].notnull())].copy()

#created MultiIndex for align with Counter duplicates
ca = c['name'].str[1]
c.index = [ca, c.groupby(ca).cumcount()]

#added condition for remove all rows with no second value in name
h = df1[((df1['name'].str[0]=='L')|(df1['name'].str[0]=='M')) & 
         (df1['ntv'] != 0.0) & (df1['name'].str[1].notnull())].copy()

#created MultiIndex for align with Counter duplicates
ha = h['name'].str[1]
h.index = [ha, h.groupby(ha).cumcount()]
print (c)
       copy name type    ntv
name                        
A    0   G1   BA    X  0.450
B    0   G1   BB    X  0.878
A    1   F2  BA1    X -7.890
B    1   F2   BB    X  2.345

print (h)
       copy name type    ntv
name                        
A    0   G1  LA1    Y  1.234
B    0   G1   LB    Y  1.056
A    1   F2   MA    Y -0.871
B    1   F2  LB1    Y  0.737
```

---

```
#join together DataFrames
df2 = pd.concat([c, h.add_suffix('_2')], axis=1)

#with real data is possible data are not aligned and get NaNs
#for remove all NaNs rows use
#df2 = df2.dropna()

df2['Model'] = df2['copy'].astype(str)+df2['name'].astype(str)+'-'+ df2['name_2'].astype(str)
#filter columns and remove MultiIndex
df2 = df2[['Model','ntv','ntv_2']].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df2)
      Model    ntv  ntv_2
0  G1BA-LA1  0.450  1.234
1   G1BB-LB  0.878  1.056
2  F2BA1-MA -7.890 -0.871
3  F2BB-LB1  2.345  0.737
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver. Thank you very much! It worked like magic and thanks a lot for your comments. They were really helpful!

Comment: I find that it's impossible to independently rename the columns, even when I open a new python file and write only a code to rename the columns. The column 'ntv_2' always has the suffice '_2' attached to the name that I give to column 1. I understand this to be what you did here in your code. But my question is that why is it still recurring even after saving the data frame and re-opening it in another python file. I got a 'None' message when I use `df.rename()`. So, I used `df.columns.str.replace('ntv_2', 'a2')` but the column is not renamed to a2.

Comment: .....It's usually renamed to the name of the other column and the suffice. I know it's a trivial question but I'm just curious and would like to know why this is the case. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm, for me always worrking perfectly `df =df.rename(columns={'ntv_2':'a2'})`, can you try it?

Comment: What I did was `df =df.rename(columns={'ntv_2':'a2'}, inplace = True)`. I took out `inplace=True` and it now works. Thank you!